# vertices with similar weights not moving at same speed

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

[image: arm and t-shirt not moving together]

As the above image shows, whenever I move the armature that controls the upper arm, the corresponding part of the t-shirt moves slower than it. This is regardless of whether or not they have the same weights.
The picture shows them at different weights, but I tested to see if the same issue arises when all weights are the same. The whole object is composed of one mesh the t-shirt and the arm are all in the same mesh. How would I prevent the arm from moving through the t-shirt?
(I know I can delete the vertices that are blocked by the t-shirt, but this same error persists even then for the remaining vertices that are slightly inside).

I am using blender v2.72b.

Answer (score 2):

Upon further playing around with the mesh, I found out that I should do the following to get what I want:

- In edit mode, select the island of the cloth mesh, in this case, the t-shirt.
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the cloth, click by "Selection".
- Go to object mode, parent the rest of the mesh to the armature, with automatic weights.
- Then parent the cloth just separated to the armature too.
- Go to pose mode and move the body, the cloth will follow it.
- Go back to object mode, select the cloth then the body, and then join the two meshes, to get back the original mesh.
- Going back to pose mode and moving the armature around still shows that the cloth follows the body's motion.

That's it, this worked for me and I hope someone will also find it helpful. If anyone has a different way of approaching this, please share.

Comment: I have another method for clothing. Instead of parenting the cloth to the armature, select the skinned object, then shift+select the cloth. Press spacebar and type/click "Transfer Weights". Then apply an armature modifier to the shirt. This makes gives better results for me.